# Does this group G have a subgroup isomorphic to G/Z(G)?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Assume that

1° $G$ is a group of order 180;

2° $Z(G)$ has order 3;

3° $G/Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $A_{5}$ (fifth alternating group);

4° every nontrivial characteristic subgroup of $G$ has order divisible by 3;

5° $G$ has exactly 10 Sylow 3- subgroups;

6° the Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$ are in number 5 and they intersect pairwise trivially;

7° every Sylow 3-subgroup of $G$ is its own centralizer in $G$;

8° for every element $t$ of order 2 in $G$, the centralizer of $t$ in $G$ is an abelian group $2 \times 2 \times 3$;

9° $G$ is made up of exactly
1 element of order 1;
15 elements of order 2, all conjugate in $G$;
62 elements of order 3;
24 elements of order 5;
30 elements of order 6;
48 elements of order 15.

(There is some redundancy, but it doesn't matter.)

My question is : do properties 1° to 9° imply that $G$ is the internal semidirect product of  $Z(G)$ with a subgroup isomorphic to $A_{5}$ ?

(If $G' < G$, it is the case, but how could we prove that $G' < G$ ?)

Edit 1 : My question got a bad note because "it doesn't show any research effort, it is unclear or not useful." The question whether the center of a given group is a direct factor of this group doesn't seem trivial to me. For example, the center of the quaternion group is not a direct factor of this group. I think my question is not within the reach of just any beginner.

Edit 2. Someone has put this on my question : "Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. "

"Interesting" or "important" are subjective matters.

"possible strategies" : I indicated a possible strategy (G' < G). This strategy is used in the proof given by Derek Holt. Derek Holt's proof relies on a theorem that is not trivial and, I think, is not in every textbook.

"why the question is relevant to you (...)  "your current progress" : well, well, looks like Math StackExchange is a tool to grab original research...

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: Also, use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your maths look pretty.

Comment: @user1729 : I just realised that mathjax plays the same role to mathematics as make-up does to people.

Comment: It follows just from 2 and 3 that $G \cong Z(G) \times A_5$ but, as user1729 says, you need to make some effort to solve the problem yourself. (If it's a semidirect product then it is obviously a direct product.) Also I don't agree that redundancy doesn't matter. Hypothesis 1 follows from 2 and 3, so why bother to say it?

Comment: I don't understand why the commentators are so rude. It happens that much easier questions get a polite answer.

Comment: @Panurge I have noticed that a few people have said my comments are rude. They are stock comments which I spent a lot of time phrasing - thought went into them. I don't think they are rude, but instead I believe that people view them as rude because the comments ask people to put in an effort which they are unwilling to do. However, I am willing to listen to any suggestions you may have on how I can improve them.

Comment: @Panurge I really don't think that anybody has been rude. I  agree that much easier questions often get answered, and the inconsistency in which questions that arguably lack context are treated is unfortunate. Anyway, I decided to answer your question before it gets closed!

Comment: "This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!" is what the help center has to say about adding context. We can debate this and you may add your personal views.  Your question is in the process of reopening following your "Edit 1" and "possible strategies" statements. The rest should not be part of the post if you wish to focus on the mathematics. Thank you , I see your previous questions have been very good, so this is just one question that had any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, it follows from Hypotheses 2 and 3 that $G \cong C_3 \times A_5$. As you point out, it is enough to prove that $[G,G] < G$, because that would imply $[G,G] \cong A_5$ and then $G = Z(G) \times [G,G]$.

This follows from the following theorem.

Let $N \le Z(G)$ with $G$ finite, $N$ a $p$-group, and let $N \le P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Then $N \cap [G,G] = N \cap [P,P]$.

The required result follows because in your problem $|P|=9$, so $P$ is abelian and $N \cap [P,P] = 1$.

The proof of the theorem is a nice application of the transfer homomorphism $\tau: G/[G,G] \to P/[P,P]$.

In general, $\tau(g)$ is a product (modulo $[P,P]$)$$\prod_{i=1}^{k}  x_i g^{r_i} x_i^{-1}$$ of conjugates of powers of $g$ that lie in $P$, where $\sum_{i=1}^k r_i = |G:P|$, and, for all $i$, we have  $x_i \in G$ and $x_ig^{r_i}x_i^{-1} \in P$.

So, if $g \in Z(G)$, then $\tau(g) = g^r$ with $r=|G:P|$. Then, under the hypotheses of the theorem, $\gcd(r,p)=1$, and hence $\tau$ induces an isomorphism $N/(N \cap [G,G]) \to N/(N \cap [P,P])$.